# How to get page to run all of js before displaying? This is used for a screenshot to pdf application, no user interaction

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I appreciate there are lots of answers that give detail on how to get a div to show a 'loading' image but this is no my dilemma.

I have a windows xp environment (can't be updated) that runs XAMPP, this uses the MS SQL dirver in XP to query an ODBC database and displays the data (this works perfectly) on a 4 weekly basis in a table. Below the table are 3 graphs all of which graph out different elements from the data (the data is phone call data that my company takes and graphs are average wait time, average answer time, call length etc).

The charts use the Google Charts API, the page then uses the URI/Base64 png created by the charts API to display the chart as an image. The use of this API does cause a delay in the page loads, so the table, detailed above, loads first but the images are updated after the page has 'finished' because the JS pushes the  back into 3 divs in the page when the chart is 'ready'.

When this page loads, taking away the delay, it looks fine.

The next step is for the contents of this page to be sent in the body of an email or as an attached pdf (whichever works) on the 1st of every month. I have a batch file on the computer that is called via scheduled tasks, which uses the PHP mail() function. The email send fine, but the images are missing. The SMTP I am using is Gmail, which does strip some code such as header elements, and also seems to change the base64 code for the PNG!

So I have opted for the create a PDF periodically then send the email once created (can be 2 separate functions if needed but I am happy doing this).

Now you have some background, here is my issue. I am using wkhtmltopdf to snapshot the page of the table and graphs, my problem is that the images created by Google do not update the HTML before the page is 'ready' therefore the screenshot taken is of the table only.

How can I delay the page being displayed or completing, before the JS for the images has finished? I will paste below what code I can to help things a little.

```
<?php
// Database stuff happens here that pulls data into table
// Then the $body is updated as the data comes through with a table around itto format it for the email.
// Body is completed below:
$body .= "</table>";
$body .= "</div>";
$body .= "</body>";
$body .= "</html>";
?>
<div id=\"ChartDIV\" style=\"height: 300px;width: 29%;float:left;margin:2%;\"></div>";
<!--Here is the javascript then that creates the charts form the table - this all works - there are three of them in the proper code-->
<script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartInOut);
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartPrcAns);
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChartAnsAbd);
function drawChartInOut() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
<?php 
//this cycles through each part of the above PHP DB query and formats it into JS
echo "['VAxis','In','Out'],";
for ($i=0;$i<count($array) ;$i++){echo "['" . $VAxis[$i] . "'," . $in[$i] . "," . $out[$i] . "],";}
?>
]);
var options = {title: 'Graph Title',};
var chart_div = document.getElementById('ChartDIV');
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
        chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
      });
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
<?php
echo $body;
?>
```

Comment: Simply, put the tool that takes the screenshot in the callback of the google visualization api. Please, show us the screenshot tool.

Comment: The 'screenshot' tool is this: http://wkhtmltopdf.org/ - this is a 3rd party application. If there is a better one, I am happy to give that a go!

Comment: I am not 100% no. Something along the lines of whent he chart has completed, do something else. But I think I will still have the same problem. The problem I have is when the page has loaded, and I view source, the divs are empty because JS has only updated them after the page has finished, meaning the 'HTML' remains unchanged.

Comment: Ok, it's a command line tool. I thought it would be executed within the DOM. The problem arises since the visualization is made asynchronous, which you can't change. The screenshot tool only waits for synchronous resources, I guess. Maybe put an artificial delay on the page itself?

Comment: I've tried having a delay in the page using setTimeout, but this just stopped the script and started it again, which didn't help.

Comment: I'm actually not sure how wkhtmltopdf does define the point in time to take the screenshot. Basically, every <img> is an external resource, that does not affect the loading time of the main document. E.g. if wkhtmltopdf simply accounts for the loading time of the main doc (specified in the command) even images wouldn't be displayed. Maybe there is an internal timeout. Anyways. Have you tried --no-stop-slow-scripts [(documentation)](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt).

Comment: Basically i think the problem is that the 'source' of the page remains unchanged, but when I 'Inspect' the page it shows the changes the JS has made, I want the modified HTML to be used not the original one. I have tried that flag, I get a 'content not found error, which is odd as it creates the pdf regardless!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118414/discussion-between-toni-and-rmj86).

Answer (score 2):

You could add a CSS style to your body that makes it invisible (CSS is executed before pageload, JQuery after pageload), load all the images (e.g. via [JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)) and then set the page visibility using JavaScript.

You just wait for the images to be loaded and then display the page that way.

```js
$('img').load(function(){
  $('body').toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```css
body {
  display:none;
  }

body.visible {
  display:block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hi! I would be visible before the image, usually. But now I wait for the page to be visible.</p>

<img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000">
```

Or if you can't afford to load JQuery (Really you shouldn't be loading JQuery in the head of your page, to improve pagespeed) in the `head` of your page, You can also do this in pure JavaScript.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.body.classList.toggle('visible')
});
```

Note that `body.classList` only has support for IE >= 10

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

If you want IE (down to 7) support checkout `classList.js` https://github.com/eligrey/classList.js

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is asking for. He/she really needs to run the screenshot tool on page ready. If your solution doesn't involve the screenshot tool, it can't help, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, but that doesn't help my situation, I don't need to hide the 'load' as the page will not be interacted with by a user, it will either be emailed as HTML into the body of an email or sent as a screenshotted PDF. I need the JS to run and complete the innerHTML updates before the page declares itself as 'ready'.

Comment: @Randy Even though this answer didn't help the OP, it helped me prevent a FOUC on a particular html page, so i decided to add a pure JS method which is more efficient :)

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt) I suggest change parameter

**--javascript-delay**        Wait some milliseconds for javascript
                                      finish (default 200)

or, even better, play with the

**--window-status**

If you set the window.status in the Google Vis callback this should be very clean. window.status is deprecated, though it might work for wkhtmltopdf.

This is an example html file wk.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <script>

      $(function(){

        $("#dynamic").css("background-color", "red");

        setTimeout(function(){
          $("#dynamic").css("background-color", "blue");
        }, 5000);

      });


    </script>

    <h1>Test page</h1>

    <div id="dynamic">
      The background color is changing...<br>
      from red<br>
      to blue!
    </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

With

```
wkhtmltopdf http://localhost/wk.html out.pdf
```

the resulting pdf shows a red background. With

```
wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 6000 http://localhost/wk.html out.pdf
```

the resulting pdf shows a blue background. **Note** the location of the --parameter, which is directly after the wkhtmltopdf programm.